# Keep Spans Inline

Tags: html, css

```html
<p style="font-size:23px;  font-weight:bold">Why Choose Ocho Rios?</p>

<span style="margin-right: 45em; display: inline;">
    <a href="https://ibb.co/yQNgjsF"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/yQNgjsF/Quality-Icon.png" 
    alt="Quality- 
    Icon" border="0" height="100"></a>
    <p>Exceptional Quality</p>
    <p>Each of our menu items is cooked <br>from fresh, high quality ingredients. <br>Our spices are 
    in- 
    house blends.</p>
    </span>

<span style="display: inline" ;>
    <a href="https://ibb.co/ggYMK0v"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/ggYMK0v/Award-Icon-2.png" alt="Award- 
    Icon-2" border="0" height="100"></a>
    <p>Exceptional Quality</p>
    <p>Each of our menu items is cooked <br>from fresh, high quality ingredients. <br>Our spices are 
    in-house blends.</p>
    </span>

<span style="margin-left: 45em; display: inline" ;>
    <a href="https://ibb.co/Px8GMDD"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/Px8GMDD/Delivery-Icon.png" 
    alt="Delivery- 
    Icon" border="0" height="100"></a>
    <p>Exceptional Quality</p>
    <p>Each of our menu items is cooked <br>from fresh, high quality ingredients. <br>Our spices are 
    in- 
    house blends.</p>
    </span>
```

Trying to get these to display all on the same line, not staggered like a staircase.

Comment: You can't have a `p` tag inside a `span` . Check the rendered output of your browser, you will most likely have all these paragraphs outside of your `spans`. First step for you is to create a valid HTML structure.

Comment: You're generally better off using `div`s as content dividers, that's kind of what they're for.

Comment: https://validator.nu/

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys, but it still isn't displaying properly. I keep getting that staircase even with the edited code. I'm using Weebly's HTML editor. The spacing from left to right is fine, but I want them all on the same "row".

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a more conventional markup for your elements:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```

Then I would use css for the row and col classes to put them in a row.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.col {
  flex: 1 1 33%;
}

img {
  height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: This will get you mostly there but you should read the guide in the link I sent so you knowhow to adjust the properties to your needs. Also I highly recommend letting the text flow without <br> tags and using css to size and position your icons and text inside the .col elements. Good luck hope this helps!